# Kruchten 4+1 Architecture View Model - Logical View is Domain Model?

Tags: architecture, uml, domain-driven-design

I try to apply the 4+1 Architecture View Model by Kruchten. Does the Logical View contain the Context Map **and** a Domain Model (entities, value objects, aggregates, domain events) from DDD?

I'm not quite sure since the level of abstraction seems to be wrong: a Domain Model wont influence my architecture. Parts of the Domain Model are very detailed ... Or is a Context Map enough?

Thanks BR

Answer (score 1):

What is enough of course depends entirely on what you would like to achieve. The 4+1 model is a means to an end and should therefore not be dictating the end. In other words, if the domain model does not fit the 4+1 model it does not mean that the context map only is enough.

As you mention, architecture is about abstraction. What is high-level is of course open for debate. I would argue that in general a context map is architectural and the inner parts of a bounded context are not, because generally those inner parts can be be abstracted and the bounded context can not. This does not mean the domain model does not need require documentation (it does, as ddd prescribes), but it means that in my opinion it should not be part of an architectural overview.